# Multiplying two char arrays in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to multiply two char arrays, `row_index` and `col_index`, here is my `row_index` and `col_index`:

```
char row_index[20] = { '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','J','K','L' };

char col_index[10] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K' };
```

so the output is **CString output[200] = {'A1', 'B1', 'C1', ... ,'KL'}**

Is there any smart / efficient way to do such task?
I am not looking for the code. I would greatly appreciate if anyone could provide me with the algorithm to do this problem!

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You've tagged 2 distinct programming languages where the *smart & efficient* way is *very dissimilar*. Please decide on exactly **one**

Comment: and the answer cannot be `char output[200] = {'A1', 'B1', 'C1', ... ,'KL'}` because `A1` does not fit into a `char`.

Comment: My mistake! Just edited to CString output[200].

Comment: I am pretty sure there is nothing more efficient than 2 for loops though, except tabling it as a constant or making the compiler to figure the table out at compile time.

Comment: I'm not sure about `CString`. `char output[200][2];` would be sufficient, `char output[200][3];` if you want to store the results as C strings (with `'\0'`). How about `std::string output[200];`?

Comment: The very nature of this question implies that true efficiency is a false requirement.  They just want something that's easy for a beginner to write and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Make an outer loop for `row_index` and an inner loop for `col_index` and concatenate the values in the inner loop. Pseudo-code for that algorithm:

```
r := 0 
while r < number_of_elements_in(row_index):
    c := 0
    while c < number_of_elements_in(col_index):
        output[r*number_of_elements_in(col_index) + c] := contatenate(col_index[c], row_index[r])
        c = c + 1
    r = r + 1
```

A possible implementation could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string row_index = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKL";
    std::string col_index = "ABCDEFGHJK";
    std::vector<std::string> output;

    output.reserve(row_index.size()*col_index.size());

    for(auto r : row_index) {
        for(auto c : col_index) {
            output.emplace_back(std::string() + c + r);
        }
    }

    for(const auto& o : output) // display result
        std::cout << o << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Your solution is much clearer than mine. I removed my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't get a good look at yours but perhaps it was clearer to OP than mine?